# How to assign input variables to member of object in java script

Tags: javascript

I create a class function with two variable string, one number and another float number. For new object, when I try to assign the user inputs to each variable of this new object, the system can not define it. `alert(s[0])` and others work fine and separate items but afterward can not assign them to function b members. Can anybody help?

```
var Book = function() {var name, author , year, price };
var b = new Book;
b.name = "abc";
b.author = "aaa";
b.year = 0;
b.price = 0.0;
var s;
b =prompt("pls enter name, author, year, price ");
s = b.split(";");
alert(s[0]);
alert(s[1]);
alert(s[2]);
alert(s[3]);
if (s.length = 4){
    b.name = s[0];
    b.author = s[1];
    b.year = s[2];
    b.price = s[3];
}
```

Comment: besides.. the s.length = 4 should be s.length == 4

Answer (score 0):

You should do a `split` on `myBook` variable instead of `b`

```js
var Book= function() {var name, author , year, price };
var b = new Book;
b.name ="abc";
b.author= "aaa";
b.year=0;
b.price=0.0;
var  s;
myBook=prompt("pls enter name, author, year, price ");
s = myBook.split(";");
alert(s[0]);
alert(s[1]);
alert(s[2]);
alert(s[3]);
    if (s.length == 4){
       b.name = s[0];
       b.author = s[1];
       b.year = s[2] ;
       b.price = s[3] ;
    }
console.log(b);
```